# How to return JSX from a method in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm pretty new to React, I'm trying to return a JSX from a method, code as follows:

```js
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


const formatName = (user) => {
    return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
}

const getGreeting = (user) => {
    if (user) {
        return {greeting}
    }
    else {
        return {forbidden}
    }
}

const user = {
    firstName: 'John',
    lastName: 'Smith'
};

const greeting = (
    <h1>Hello {formatName(user)}</h1>
);

const forbidden = (
    <h1>Hello stranger!</h1>
);

const element = (
    <div>{getGreeting(user)}</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    element, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

As you can see, `element` contains a div which I wish to render `getGreeting`, since `user == true`, it should return `greeting`, which calls the method `formatName`. However it returns an error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {greeting}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if you've found any of the answers helpful - please accept one as the right answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getGreeting` should return a JSX and not an object

try this:

```
const greeting = (
    <h1>Hello {formatName(user)}</h1>
);

const forbidden = (
    <h1>Hello stranger!</h1>
);

const getGreeting = (user) => {
    if (user) {
        return greeting
    }
    else {
        return forbidden
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `return {greeting}` to `return greeting` without the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, when you write:

`return {greeting}`

...what you are saying is "return an object, with a property named 'greeting', which is set to value of the variable `greeting`"

The last part of that, where the value is set, is an ES6 shortcut, essentially replacing `{ "greeting": greeting }` with `{greeting}` for brevity's sake.

In other words, you are currently returning an object with a single property, "greeting", which is basically what your error message says. 
What you are returning is:

```
{
    "greeting": <h1>Hello ... </h1>
}
```

What you want to return is:

```
<h1>Hello ... </h1>
```

Since your `greeting` const is valid JSX, you can just return it directly! i.e. `return greeting;`